# append String to ngModel to get an expression

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I have a Business Object `Car{id:2,name:ford,modelNo:123}` I also have a MetaData class for CarMetaData`{columnName:string,type:text,required:true}` 
each attribute has it's own CarMetaData object 
how can I display `Car` data in a form in such a way using an Array of CarMetaData objects

In the template.html file

```
<form #carForm='ngForm'>
 <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let metaData of metadata" >
   <input [(ngModel)]="car[metaData.columnName]" name="metaData.columnName" 
    type="text">
 </div>
</form>
```

In the component file

```
car:Car;
metadata:CarMetaData[];
```

The above method isn't working because of the [] in car[meta.columnName] in the
ngModel is there a way an expression can be worked out in *ngFor or [(ngModle)] to calculate columName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very stupid mistake. Please try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let meta of metaData;">
  <input [(ngModel)]="car[meta.columnName]" name="{{meta.columnName}}"  />
  {{meta.columnName}}
</div>
```

---

**Old answer:**

But first - your loop (`meta in metaData`) is wrong as you loop array, not object. So you better do `let meta of metaData, let i = index`.

And the interesting part is how `ngModel` sets the value of inputs in `ngFor`. If you try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let meta of metaData; let i = index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="car[meta.columnName]" name="meta.columnName"  />
  {{meta.columnName}}
</div>
```

You will see that input value is the same of all inputs (it was picked from the first ngFor iteration and repeated to all inputs). However, `{{meta.columnName}}` prints correct values. So there is some scoping issue. Other strange thing - its definitely related with `ngForm` and input's `name` property. If you move that outside of the form - all happens as expected. And if you:

```
<div *ngFor="let meta of metaData; let i = index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="car[meta.columnName]" name="{{metaData[i].columnName}}"  />
  {{meta.columnName}}
</div>
```

Inside the form - again, all works well.  So that might be your workaround.

Here is a [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtodfo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). Hopefully someone will explain it further.

Comment: ya, I have corrected the loop and with the ngModel the meta.columnName returns a new value because it is a metadata object of a different column and yes car[meta.columnName] works outside the form but doesn't work within the form I don't get It

Comment: hey, you got it right though but what will the effect be if I add custom filters in the form of pipes. suppose I have a pipe which filters non-editable fields like Id. for me the Iterator is getting past it which is causing metaData[i] to be a different value than that of meta.columnName

Comment: Ups, I just noticed very stupid mistake - I was wondering why formControl instances gets un-interpolated names... Hm, because they are not interpolated... Here I update

Comment: ya just interpolation is working like name={{meta.columnName}}

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to put both objects in a wrapper-object. e.g.

```
export class CarWrapper {
    constructor(
       car: Car,
       carMetaData: CarMetaData
    ) {}
}
```

Then build a method that joins both objects in this wrapper

```
private carWrapper: Array<CarWrapper> = [];

private fillCarWrapper(): void {
    // your code here
}
```

And in your template you act like this

```
<form #carForm='ngForm'>
   <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let wrapper of carWrapper">
      <input [(ngModel)]="wrapper.car" name="wrapper.carMetaData.columName" type="text">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hey, @DiabolicWords I've Tried this method too but ultimately I want the object to be saved in an easier way. By doing this I need to separate the BO from the merged object